# ensure filter printable char in jquery on keyup event

Tags: jquery, key, keyup

How can I ensure that user press "printable" character in jquery?

I try this but it doesn't work

```
$("#foo").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.charCode) {
        console.debug('this is printable char');
    }
});
```

I would want only numbers, A-Z a-z character, and also "è,$,%" etc, but not arrow, enter,f5 etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2291807/149206

Comment: Only numbers, A-Z a-z character, and also "è,$,%" etc, but not arrow, enter,f5 etc

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#foo").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which < 0x20) {
        console.debug('this is not printable char');
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.debug('this is printable char');
    }
});
```

Comment: space is printable - it would not catch it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
            alert(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode|e.charCode));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Seems tow work just fine with jQuery 1.4.2, FF, IE, Chrome.

To delve into the mess that is JS keyboard event handling, see: 
[JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284844/jquery-how-to-filter-out-non-character-keys-on-keypress-event/2291807#2291807)